# Handling 2 different DOM on CSS_SELECTOR PYTHON Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Im working on ig bot liker, then im facing issues...
here the condition:

In this bot goals is liking and avoid to unlike post that already liked...

i use `CSS_SELECTOR` to find DOM..and the issue is when like button  clicked, the `CSS_SELECTOR DOM` also changing...

before liked:

```
section._aamu._aat0 > span._aamw > button > div._abm0._abl_ > span > svg

attribute > aria-label : 'like'
```

after liked:

```
section._aamu._aat0 > span._aamw > button > div > span > svg

attribute > aria-label : 'Unlike'
```

So in this case i cant use condition when `aria-label` value changing.

so i make 2 `def` for this..

for `aria-label: 'like'` condition:

```
def like():
    print('Check if Like')
    likec = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section._aamu._aat0 > span._aamw > button > div._abm0._abl_ > span > svg') #Span 
    likecval = likec.get_attribute('aria-label') == 'Like' 
    
    if likecval:
        print('[INFO] : Ready to like...')
        likec.click()  
        print('[INFO] : Liking Done!')
    else:
        print('i have no idea')
like()
```

for `aria-label: 'Unlike'` condition:

```
def unlike():
    print('Check if Unlike')
    unlikec = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section._aamu._aat0 > span._aamw > button > div > span > svg') #Span 
    unlikedcval = unlikec.get_attribute('aria-label') == 'Unlike' 
    if unlikedcval:
        print('[INFO] : Already liked this post!')
    else:
        print('i have no idea')
unlike()
```

But if i run these, im facing error with these error condition:

- when the post already liked, the `like` module error, # no such element
- when the post not yet liked, the `unlike` module error. # no such element

anybody can help this issue? or maybe, how to combine those in to one nested condition.
thanks

Comment: You wrote you want to avoid unliking a post, why is there a `unlike()` function then? Can you just find the button and check for aria label - if its value is `like`, click it, if not, ignore it and continue? As for module error, are you sure all elements are always called the way you described above? I've previously run into website that generate their elements dynamically with a dynmic names that change every time the site was loaded.

Comment: i make 2, because i dont know to ignore or continue when the script couldnt find the DOM.. it always error NoSuch... so, how to make it to just continue if not meet the condition?

Comment: That's a case for [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). Using `try: ...your code...` and `except Exception: pass` will silently ignore the error. Instead of `pass` you can print your own message. This will prevent the code from stopping.

Comment: ok i will try now....

Comment: i already test with try, but still facing an error, because it cant find element :No Such Element....it because cant find  CSS Selector DOM..